# Failed to compile ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui, babeljs

I'm stuck with this error below:

> Failed to compile ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/assertThisInitialized' in 'E:\IT\the-venue\node_modules@material-ui\core\ButtonBase'

Since the problem has to do something with Babel I've installed the latest version coming from Babel's website (https://babeljs.io/setup#installation). 
I've only done it until step 2, because the step 3 requires 'react' replacement with 'babel'in the 'scripts' section ('build' line) and I am not sure if I should do this.

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "the-venue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.9",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5"
  }
}
```

I am working with Material UI and the expected result is the webpage with the header from Material UI (App Bar).
Would anyone explain what the problem is and help me solve it, please ?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-material-dashboard-pro-react/issues/62

Comment: Thank you, Ruan. I already saw the resource you had posted and thought that the only thing the guy had done back in 2018 was installing the latest version of Babel.  As I wrote I already did that before asking the question here. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you using a very old version of `@material-ui/core`?

Comment: Hello. I don't know. Might be. I am passing the Udemy React course which was last updated a year ago. I copy-pasted this from the guide '''npm install @material-ui/core@1.2.0 @material-ui/icons@1.1.0 react-reveal@1.2.2 react-scroll@1.7.9 react-slick@0.23.1 --save'''. I could not find the number of latest version on Material UI website.

Comment: It's always trial and error with this, check versioning requirements and play around with different versions of Material / relevant packages.

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install @material-ui/core@latest @material-ui/icons@latest react-reveal@1.2.2 react-scroll@1.7.9 react-slick@0.23.1
```

Do this and get the latest version of material-ui/core & material-ui/icons.
This will solve your problem.